# Some fields are missing in the fieldexplorer. How to show all fields?

Tags: crystal-reports

i'm using Crystal Reports with my ERP-System. There have been predefined reports i now want to change.

In the field-explorer are some tables which have been renamed for better readability. But those tables are missing some fields, i want to use. If i connect the whole table again, all fields are there. Is there a way to display all fields in the predefined tables.

I tried to refresh the Database but nothing changes. If i delete the predefined table and then rename the new one to the old one, so i can use all predefinded formulas, all used fields in the report get deleted. I would need to recreate the whole report then.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you doing it through Database Expert? Map the new table with the existing table? and then it adds the new fields?? If you are doing that I dont see any other way besides that. I know it sucks as it will prompt you that existing fields will be deleted. Althought I am not sure thats the case.

Comment: well im i'm adding the new table in CR through the database-assistent. if i delete the old table there is no prompt but it still deletes all fields from the report. Not the formulas though

Comment: I dont think u need to delete the old table. Just use Left and Right arrows to move new table and new fields will be added to the existing table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is truly the same table and is not showing all the fields then you need to do "Database > Verify Database".  That will force CR to refresh the structure of the table (instead of just the data).  If this doesn't add the missing fields then the table in the report is actually a different object.

To see what the table/view the report is actually using go to "Database > Set DataSource Location" and look at the properties node for that table.  It will show if it is a table/view/SP and what the true object name is.

If you want to replace the existing table with a different table you go to "Database > Set DataSource Location" again.  Highlight the existing table in the top window, connect and highlight the replacement table in the bottom window. Then click update. Crystal will replace one table with the other and all of the fields in the report that exist in the new table will be mapped automatically.  Note that the new table will keep the alias of the original table.  If you are unsure if the table was updated you can look at the properties node in the top window to see the change.

Comment: Verify Database did the job. Thank you.